# Cassandra sstableloader authorization

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Small question about Cassandra 3.0.8. Not datastax.
 is it possible to grant/revoke permissions for users, who use sstableloader? For now, user only authenticate in Cassandra and can update any table...

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific authentication for just sstableloader. However you can

- Create separate set of users/roles for each and every table within the keyspace.
- In other words, there could be different users with different set of permissions on each and every table.
- Here is an example on how to create user and define permission at table level

> GRANT SELECT PERMISSIONS ON keyspace1.table1 TO USER1;
>     GRANT MODIFY PERMISSIONS ON keyspace1.table2 TO USER1;

So in the above example USER1 has select permission on table1 while update permission on table2. So you can authorize who gets to have update access on table1 but not if it comes from sstableloader or cql or application code.

Here is the reference for roles and permissions https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/grant_r.html

Comment: I can't agree. If user know table's absolute name , then he can import data into this table. No matter, which authorization he has at csql level...

Comment: May be its because sstableloader behave like Cassandra node

Comment: @IlyaSa Have you tried what you mentioned above? SSTABLELOADER with username/pwd that doesn't have authorization to that table.

Comment: Can you give screenshot about the permissions of the user and sstableloader finishing successfully with that user on a table that it doesn’t have permission on

Comment: Sorry, I can't. User, which made modification in table via sstableloader, has only SELECT permissions on this table in csql

Comment: I'm using 'LIST ALL PERMISSIONS ON' for investigation. I've checked permissions on key space and on table

Comment: Can you import data in your environment? Or this problem happens to me only?